# Change page loading from automatically to when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

ok, I have the code below which puts in a page loader whilst the page is loading, this problem I have is I only want the page loader to show when a button is clicked rather than every time the page loads up.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to implement it into the javascript code I have below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<input type="submit" class="visitpage" name="Submit" value="Update Results" rel="nofollow"/>

$('body').append('<div style="" id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader">Loading...</div></div>');
$(window).on('load', function(){
  setTimeout(removeLoader, 500); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
});
function removeLoader(){
$( "#loadingDiv" ).fadeOut(500, function() {
  // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
  $( "#loadingDiv" ).remove(); //makes page more lightweight 
  });  
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$(window).on('load',`, a click event on the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your code like this

```js
$(".visitpage").on('click', function(){
 $('body').append('<div style="" id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader">Loading...</div></div>');
 setTimeout(removeLoader, 500); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
});
function removeLoader(){
$( "#loadingDiv" ).fadeOut(500, function() {
  // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
  $( "#loadingDiv" ).remove(); //makes page more lightweight 
  });  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit" class="visitpage" name="Submit" value="Update Results" rel="nofollow"/>
```

The only change is to assing showing loader to difrent event, in this case click of button.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code in a clean way

```
<input type="submit" class="visitpage" name="Submit" value="Update Results"/>
<div id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader">Loading...</div></div>

<script>
$('#loadingDiv').hide();
$('.visitpage').on('click', function(){
    $('#loadingDiv').fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loadingDiv').fadeOut(); 
    }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

of course, you must include the jQuery library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Enjoy :)